# SSH into Homestead Using Git Bash on Windows Characters Not Displayed Properly

Tags: git, bash, ssh

After running:

```
homestead ssh
```

and logging into the VM everything looks okay until you're typing certain commands or viewing command results where the characters aren't rendered properly so you get output for ls that looks like this:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ ls
←[0m←[34;42mprojects←[0m
```

Is there a way to get this to render these characters properly in Git bash on windows 8.1?

Also the cursor can appear in strange places if you run commands like:

```
mysql -uhomestead -p
```

With windows am I just forced to use Putty to get this to work properly?

**UPDATE**

It appears to be ANSI colour codes not being displayed.  I've already added color.ui = true to gitconfig so not sure why this occurs unless Git SSH renders things differently?  Since I get colour output when using the bash and but not using SSH.

**UPDATE**

Tried re-installing GIT to see if I had other options and noticed that I was given an option for using (tortoise)plink instead of OpenSSH.  I downloaded the Putty plink.exe and provided its path, but homestead SSH still doesn't render the ANSI color code, and doesn't open Putty instead...  not sure what was supposed to happen if you provided plink path, but assumed it would use Putty instead?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the easiest solution on windows is to use [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/?source=typ_redirect) as a wrapper for Git Bash and it takes care of rendering any ANSI color codes.